# opDispatch and compile time parameters

Tags: d

How can I use opDispatch for forwarding to method with compile time parameters. See code below:

```
import std.stdio;

struct B{
    auto p1(T)(T arg) {
        writeln( "p1: ", arg );
    }
    auto p2(T, int C)(T s) {
        writeln( "p2: ", s, " / ", C);
    }
}

struct C(T) {
    T b;

    auto opDispatch(string s, Args...)(Args args) {
        mixin("b."~s)(args);
    }
}

void main() {
     C!B b;
     //fine: compiler is smart enough
    b.p1("abc");
    //oops: "no property 'p2' for type ..."
    b.p2!(int, 10)(5);
    B origB;
    //fine:
    origB.p2!(int, 10)(5);
 }
```

**EDIT**

Replace class with struct: avoid usage of CTFE for field initialization with `new`. It is not related to my question.

Comment: I'm actually not sure this can be done. I did manage to get `    b.opDispatch!("p2",int, 10)(5);` working, but not `b.p2!(int, 10)(5);`. You'd think they are the same thing but apparently not.

Comment: I think errors generated by opDispatch are dropped in favor of a "no property" message, so you won't get the actual error message. But I think the mixin is ill-formed, it's not a complete statement. I think the `(args)` parameter pass belongs into the mixin, and don't forget the semicolon

Comment: Instead of `opDispatch`, you can try `alias b this;`.

Comment: It is simplified version. I can't use `alias b this`

Comment: Quite interesting problem indeed. Maybe it is a good idea to ask on the D newsgroups (http://forum.dlang.org). I am curious whether there is a solution or not.

Comment: Yes I agree about forum.dlang.org: http://forum.dlang.org/thread/gbofspdhsfiwxvsbytoa@forum.dlang.org

Comment: Please answer your own post once you solve the problem! You already got an upvote from me for the question. :)

Comment: I will check @Meta answer from dlang forum and I think he will repost answer here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

D template system is very powerful.  This is more generic solution:

```
import std.stdio;
class B {
    auto p1(T)(T arg) { writeln( "p1: ", arg ); }
    auto p2(T, int C)(T s) { writeln( "p2: ", s, " / ", C); }
}
class C(T) {
    T b = new T;
    template opDispatch(string s) {
        template opDispatch(TARGS...) {
            auto opDispatch(ARGS...)(ARGS args) {
                static if(TARGS.length) return mixin("b." ~ s ~ "!TARGS(args)");
                else return mixin("b." ~ s ~ "(args)");
            }
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    auto b = new C!(B)();
    b.p1("abc");
    b.p2!(int, 10)(5);
}
```

http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/791c65d0e4ee

Answer (score 1):

If indeed this is not possible with `opDispatch` as Adam D. Ruppe's answer suggests, then your only recourse might be to turn to string mixins, which are a bit ugly but incredibly powerful. Unless using `opDispatch` is a hard requirement, string mixins might be the only way.

Luckily, most of the work to do this is [already done](https://github.com/MetaLang/phobos/commit/cfdbb39657ff4273a0454af45638b8a83b416f9f) (and it's more involved than you might think). The code itself is hairy, but all you need to do is as follows:

```
import std.stdio;

class B{
    auto p1(T)(T arg) {
        writeln( "p1: ", arg );
    }
    auto p2(T, int C)(T s) {
        writeln( "p2: ", s, " / ", C);
    }
}

class C(T) {
    T b = new T;

    mixin(forwardToMember!(b, "p1", "p2"));
}

void main() {
    auto b = new C!(B)();
    b.p1("abc");

    //This now compiles and correctly forwards to b.b.p2
    b.p2!(int, 10)(5);
}
```

I've included the code below with all the unittests stripped. It's important to note that `forwardToMember` currently doesn't support overloads for regular functions; it'll just pick the first instance of the specified function that it finds. I *think* they *should* work for template functions, however.

```
import std.traits;
import std.meta;

private alias isSomeStringType(alias str) = isSomeString!(typeof(str));

template forwardToMember(alias member, symbols...)
if (symbols.length > 0 && allSatisfy!(isSomeStringType, symbols))
{
    static if (symbols.length == 1)
    {
        static assert(hasMember!(typeof(member), symbols[0]),
            "Cannot dispatch: member '" ~ member.stringof ~
                "' does not support method '" ~ symbols[0] ~ "'");

        enum forwardToMember = genWrapperMixin!(member, symbols[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        enum forwardToMember = forwardToMember!(member, symbols[0]) ~ forwardToMember!(member, symbols[1..$]);
    }
}

private enum SymbolKind
{
    function_,
    property,
    templateFunction,
    fieldFunction,
    field,
    aliasableSym,
}

//Ugly hack but there's no other way to do this
private template isTemplateFunction(f...)
if (f.length == 1)
{
    import std.algorithm: among, balancedParens, canFind, count;

    static if (!__traits(isTemplate, f[0]))
    {
        enum isTemplateFunction = false;
    }
    else
    {
        enum fstr = f[0].stringof;

        //A template function's .stringof is of the format <function name>(<template args>)(<function args>)
        //so match on the number of brackets to determine whether it's a template function or not
        enum isTemplateFunction = __traits(isTemplate, f)
                                    && fstr.balancedParens('(', ')')
                                    && (fstr.canFind("if")
                                            || fstr.count!(c => cast(bool)c.among!('(', ')')) == 4);
    }
}

private template getSymbolKind(Aggregate, string symbol)
{
    import std.traits;
    import std.typetuple;

    enum getMemberMixin = "Aggregate." ~ symbol;

    //Appears in Aggregate.tupleof so it must be a field
    static if (staticIndexOf!(symbol, FieldNameTuple!Aggregate) > -1)
    {
        //Check if it's a regular field or a function pointer
        static if (isSomeFunction!(mixin(getMemberMixin)))
            enum getSymbolKind = SymbolKind.fieldFunction;
        else
            enum getSymbolKind = SymbolKind.field;
    }
    else
    {
        static if (isSomeFunction!(mixin(getMemberMixin))
                        && !__traits(isStaticFunction, mixin(getMemberMixin))
                        || isTemplateFunction!(mixin(getMemberMixin)))
        {
            static if (isTemplateFunction!(mixin(getMemberMixin)))
                enum getSymbolKind = SymbolKind.templateFunction;
            else static if (functionAttributes!(mixin(getMemberMixin)) & FunctionAttribute.property)
                enum getSymbolKind = SymbolKind.property;
            else
                enum getSymbolKind = SymbolKind.function_;
        }
        //If it's not a member function/property then it should be an aliasable static symbol
        else static if (__traits(compiles, { alias _ = Alias!(mixin(getMemberMixin)); }))
            enum getSymbolKind = SymbolKind.aliasableSym;
        else
            static assert(0, "Error: " ~ Aggregate.stringof ~ "." ~ symbol ~ " is not a member function, field, or aliasable symbol");
    }
}

private template genWrapperMixin(alias member, string symbol)
{
    import std.algorithm: among;
    import std.string: format;

    enum symbolKind = getSymbolKind!(typeof(member), symbol);

    static if (symbolKind.among!(SymbolKind.function_, SymbolKind.property, SymbolKind.fieldFunction))
    {
        alias MethodType = FunctionTypeOf!(mixin("member." ~ symbol));
        enum funAttrs = functionAttributes!MethodType;
        enum methodIsStatic = __traits(isStaticFunction, mixin("member." ~ symbol));
        enum funAttrStr = getFunctionAttributeStr(funAttrs) ~ (methodIsStatic ? " static" : "");

        //Workaround Issue 14913
        enum returnStr = funAttrs & FunctionAttribute.return_ ? "return" : "";

        enum genWrapperMixin = q{
            %3$s
            auto ref %2$s(ParameterTypeTuple!(FunctionTypeOf!(%1$s.%2$s)) args) %4$s
            {
                import std.functional: forward;

                return %1$s.%2$s(forward!args);
            }
        }
        .format(member.stringof, symbol, funAttrStr, returnStr);
    }
    else static if (symbolKind == SymbolKind.templateFunction)
    {
        enum genWrapperMixin =  q{
            template %2$s(TemplateArgs...)
            {
                auto ref %2$s(FunArgs...)(auto ref FunArgs args)
                {
                    import std.functional: forward;

                    return %1$s.%2$s!(TemplateArgs)(forward!args);
                }
            }
        }
        .format(member.stringof, symbol);
    }
    else static if (symbolKind == SymbolKind.field)
    {
        alias FieldType = typeof(mixin("member." ~ symbol));
        alias FA = FunctionAttribute;
        enum attrStr = getFunctionAttributeStr(FA.pure_ | FA.nothrow_ | FA.safe | FA.nogc);
        enum genWrapperMixin = q{
            @property %3$s %4$s %1$s()
            {
                return %2$s.%1$s;
            }

            @property %3$s void %1$s(%4$s val)
            {
                %2$s.%1$s = val;
            }
        }
        .format(symbol, member.stringof, attrStr, FieldType.stringof);
    }
    else static if (symbolKind == SymbolKind.aliasableSym)
    {
        enum genWrapperMixin = q{
            alias %1$s = %2$s.%1$s;
        }
        .format(symbol, member.stringof);
    }
    else
        static assert(member.stringof ~ "." ~ symbol ~ " has unexpected kind '" ~ symbolKind.to!string);
}

private string getFunctionAttributeStr(FunctionAttribute funAttrs)
{
    import std.algorithm: among, filter, joiner, map, strip;
    import std.conv: to;

    string funAttrStr;
    with (FunctionAttribute)
    {
        funAttrStr = [EnumMembers!FunctionAttribute]
                        .filter!(e => (funAttrs & e) && e != none && e != ref_ && e != return_)
                        .map!(e => e.to!string.strip('_'))
                        .map!(s => s.among!("safe", "trusted", "system", "nogc", "property") ? '@' ~ s : s)
                        .joiner(" ")
                        .to!string;
    }

    return funAttrStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the eponymous template pattern, and have an opDispatch function with your compile-time parameters inside an outer opDispatch template that takes the regular opDispatch string parameter. You can also have multiple inner opDispatch functions (and fields) that follow regular overload rules.

```
import std.stdio;

struct Foo {

    public template opDispatch(string name) {

        public string opDispatch() {
            return name;
        }

        public T opDispatch(T)() {
           return T.init;
        }

        public string opDispatch(T)(string s) {
            return name ~ ' ' ~ T.stringof ~ ' ' ~ s;
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    Foo foo;
    writeln( foo.bar );
    writeln( foo.baz!int );
    writeln( foo.foo!Foo("foo") );
}
```

Produces the output:

```
bar
0
foo Foo foo
```

DPaste link: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/6e5cfca8b702

Comment: I want create general wrapper and I can't predict all possible opDispatch variants. I will check @Meta answer (from dlang forum). He suggests to use special forwardToMember mixin

Comment: The original implementation of `forwardToMember` used `opDispatch`, but I chose to use mixin declarations instead because the user may already define a competing `opDispatch`. Also, if the struct/class is changed later to add, for example, a `p2` member (or it already has one), the `opDispatch` implementation will silently be shadowed, instead of the error you will get from a mixin declaration.